# How to sign data with Certificate's Private key in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, cryptography, certificate, rsa, private-key

I need to sign data before sending it to a service. I did it in a windows application by following method:

```
private string SignWithPfx(string data)
    {
        var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "certificate.pfx";
        var password = "1234";

        var collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();

        collection.Import(path, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        var certificate = collection[0];
        var publicKey = certificate.PublicKey.Key as RSACryptoServiceProvider;

        var privateKey = certificate.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;


        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        rsa.FromXmlString(certificate.PrivateKey.ToXmlString(true));

        var signature = rsa.SignData(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data), CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
    }
```

but when I transfered it to a Silverlight project I noticed that there is not "X509Certificate2Collection" or even "RSACryptoServiceProvider"!
What should I have to do?

Comment: RSA functionality is present in Silverlight but I don't see any support for .pfx / PKCS#12 (same thing). You may have to use BouncyCastle for .NET: `Org.BouncyCastle.Pkcs.Pkcs12Store.GetKey(string)`

Comment: Silverlight has just over 1000 days left before full end of life (1002 as of today: https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/installation-win-SL5.html => `2021-10-12`); you're probably better off looking for a way to replace it than how to work around something it doesn't have public API for.

Comment: Flash? No. Java Applets? No. Plugins? No, being deprecated. VB script? I hope not. Well, that leaves ECMA Script and / or HTML 5 I suppose :)

Comment: Actually, there is an old framework based on silverlight which we are going update it by .net core. since then we have no choice to maintenance it.